# Update only one column in table SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here, I have six column in the table. All data success to be insert but when update, I just want column active to be update which is contain value yes or no for checked checkbox and unchecked checkbox. Is it possible to update only one column?
I'm really working on it but the result are bad.

[image: Data]

One column get blank like positionTemplateID and there is problem a little bit more which is LA9 should be 'y' isntead of 'n' because it is checked checkbox. And LA16 should be 'n' in column active because uchecked checkbox.

> PHP for update

```
function updateTemplate(){
global $ehorsObj;
$employeeID = $_SESSION['employeeID'];
$propertyID = $_SESSION['propertyID'];
$positionTemplateID = (isset($_POST['positionTemplateID']) ? $_POST['positionTemplateID'] : '');
$id = (isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '');
$progid  = (isset($_POST['progid']) ? $_POST['progid'] : '');
$active  = (isset($_POST['active']) ? $_POST['active'] : '');`

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblHrsPositionProgramTemplate 
            WHERE hrsPositionID = '".$id."'
            AND programID = '".$progid[$x]."'
            AND active = '".$active."'";
    $GetResult = $ehorsObj->FetchData($sql, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);
    for($x=0; $x< sizeof($progid); $x++ )

{

    $sqlActive = "UPDATE tblHrsPositionProgramTemplateLog
                    SET active = '".$active."
                    WHERE programID = '".$progid[$x]."'";   
    $ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sqlActive, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS); 

    if ($active == "n") {

    $sqlActive .= " SET active = 'y' ";

        $positionTemplateIDLog = $ehorsObj->EHORS_PK("tblHrsPositionProgramTemplateLog");   
        $sqlAddLog = "INSERT  INTO tblHrsPositionProgramTemplateLog 
                    SET positionTemplateIDLog = '" . $positionTemplateIDLog . "',
                    positionTemplateID = '" . $positionTemplateID . "',
                    programID = '" . $progid[$x] . "',
                    hrsPositionID  = '" . $id . "',
                    propertyID   = '" . $propertyID . "',
                    employeeID  = '" . $employeeID . "',
                    dateTimeEmployee = NOW() ,
                    active = 'y' ";         

        $ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sqlAddLog, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);
    } else {

    $sqlActive .= " SET active = 'n' ";

        $positionTemplateIDLog = $ehorsObj->EHORS_PK("tblHrsPositionProgramTemplateLog");   
        $sqlAddLog = "INSERT  INTO tblHrsPositionProgramTemplateLog 
                    SET positionTemplateIDLog = '" . $positionTemplateIDLog . "',
                    positionTemplateID = '" . $positionTemplateID . "',
                    programID = '" . $progid[$x] . "',
                    hrsPositionID  = '" . $id . "',
                    propertyID   = '" . $propertyID . "',
                    employeeID  = '" . $employeeID . "',
                    dateTimeEmployee = NOW() ,
                    active = 'n' ";      

        $ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sqlAddLog, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);
        }   
}}
```

Comment: based on your code, you are updating 1 column which is `active`.

Comment: Yes absolutely. Because i want to update the value 'y' or 'n' in column active based on programID (checkboxes)@ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ